# Sending e-mail when SNMP Trap is received

Tags: email, net-snmp, snmp

I have to configure SNMP trap receiver to handle traps from a particular device (in this case it is a IBM TS3584 Tape Library) and send them over (as e-mail) with the information about the error. My server is running CentOS 6.4 linux, with net-snmp package.

I have connected to the library and I am able to receive its test trap. Additionaly I've downloaded the MIBs for this device (from here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ssg1S4000318), and verified that I can get the values (or OID) of a particular event:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public -m +IBM-TS3500-MIBv2 10.10.100.5 ibm3584MIBObjectsTD
**IBM-TS3500-MIBv1::ibm3584MIBObjectsTD.0 = STRING: "This is a test SNMP trap."**


snmptranslate -m +IBM-TS3500-MIBv2 -IR -On ibm3584MIBObjectsTD
**.1.3.6.1.4.1.2.6.182.1.2.71.1**
```

The whole trap (from /var/log/messages) looks like this:

```
2013-08-27 15:49:37 10.10.100.5(via UDP: [10.10.100.5]:1795->[10.10.100.135]) TRAP,
SNMP v1, community public#012#011SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.4484.1 Enterprise Specific
Trap (408) Uptime: 1:00:10.45#012#011SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2.6.182.1.2.11.1 =
STRING: "3584 L32 7814014"#011SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2.6.182.1.2.111.1 = STRING: "
0"#011SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2.6.182.1.2.101.1 = ""#011SNMPv2
SMI::enterprises.2.6.182.1.2.41.1 = STRING: "08"#011SNMPv2
SMI::enterprises.2.6.182.1.2.71.1 = STRING: "This is a test SNMP trap."#011SNMPv2
SMI::enterprises.2.6.182.1.2.151.1 = INTEGER: 1#011SNMPv2
SMI::enterprises.2.6.182.1.2.161.1 = STRING: "00000"
```

My question is: is there any software (linux, non gui) which can handle the traps received in this format and basing on the severity (which is one value in the SNMP trap) send an e-mail using the informations provided in a trap? I've tried Cacti, but I couldn't find any notification options (except an old plugin with no documentation), and although I managed cacti to speak with my device (reading its name/location etc.) its useless. AFAIK Nagios has the plugin for TS3200/3300 Libraries, but I can't use Nagios.

So I'm thinking if I have to write my own parser tailing /var/log/messages for snmp traps and search for the informations or is there any solution I can use?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure `snmptrapd` to handle traps with a script; this is the `traphandle` directive.

I believe the configuration file is `/etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf`.

For example, you can use:

```
traphandle IBM-TS3500-MIBv1::ibm3584MIBObjectsTD.0 /usr/local/bin/myscript.pl
```

Or, to parse everything, you can use:

```
traphandle default /usr/local/bin/myscript.pl
```

The contents of the trap is passed to the script in `STDIN` so your script will need to read from there.

You don't mention your preferred language for scripting this so I won't go into too much detail; however, the following library exists for Perl: [SNMP::Trapinfo](https://metacpan.org/pod/SNMP::Trapinfo)

You could do something like this:

```
use strict;
use SNMP::Trapinfo;
my $trap = SNMP::Trapinfo->new(*STDIN, {hide_passwords => 1});
# parse trap here
my $subject = "Got trap from $trap->hostname";
open EMAIL, "|-", "/usr/bin/Mail", "-s", $subject, "me@mydomain.com";
print EMAIL "My Email Body for SNMP Trap";
close EMAIL;
```

Additionally, it doesn't look like your traps are being fully translated in `/var/log/messages`. I can't remember which variables you need to set to translate the traps with custom MIBs but you should be able to drop your MIBs in /usr/local/share/snmp/mibs (creating that directory if it doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

Update2:
http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmptrapd.html
Search for more.

Update: net-snmp trap receiver snmptrapd.

http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial-5/demon/

Do you want a full monitoring system that can handle traps? If so, try Opennms. It is the most mature of the open source monitoring products.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't need a full monitoring system for now, but I will sure dig into Opennms - maybe it will be handy in the future. For now I need to parse these particular traps and (in case of error) send e-mail containing the information from the trap. EDIT: Yes, I am using snmptrapd right now to capture the trap, but I don't know how to pass it, as the documentation in the link you provided for snmptrapd is not yet written. EDIT2: Yes, I've read this man page, but I didn't find any useful information regarding my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **snmptrapd** for receiving traps (the service is listening on port 162/udp) and for further processing **snmptt** (see http://snmptt.sourceforge.net/docs/snmptt.shtml).